# Shifting a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite, perturbation-theory

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a semi-positive definite matrix. What can we say about the matrix

$$ A_h:= A+(h-1)I,  $$

where $I$ is the identity matrix, and $h>0$ (interested here in small $h$)?

I believe there will be an $h_0$ such that for all $h<h_0$, $A_h$ is invertible. But I wonder if there is anything else we can say about $A_h$, can I get lower (and upper) bounds on $\langle A_h(x-y),x-y\rangle$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say a lot about $A_h$ since the identity matrix $I$ commutes with every other matrix. For simplicity I assume that $A$ is diagonizable.

Thus there is an orthogonal matrix $B$ such that $BAB^{-1}=D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal. Then we have
$$ BA_hB^{-1}=BAB^{-1}+(h-1)BIB^{-1}=D+(h-1)I\, ,$$
since $BI=IB$.

In conclusion: we used that $A_h$ has the same eigenbasis as $A$ and saw that the eigenvalues of $A_h$ are given by the entries on the diagonal of $D_h:=D+(h-1)I$. $A_h$ is invertible if $D_h$ is and the eigenvalues will give you a lower and upper bound on $\langle A_hv,v\rangle$ aswell.

Comment: and is it possible to show $D_h$ is invertible for small enough $h$?

Comment: Yes, $D_h$ is invertible if and only if every diagonal entry $\lambda_k+(h-1)$ is non-zero. Since there are only finitely many $\lambda_k>1$ there is a small enough $h>0$ such that $D_h$ is invertible.